# Trying to install RStudio on a Ubuntu 22.04 Raspberry Pi 4 2GB memory

Tags: r, rstudio

I am trying to install RStudio to complete some basic non-CPU intensive tasks.

I download the `.deb` file and run the following:

```
matt@matt-Rpi-2GB:~/Downloads$ sudo gdebi rstudio-2022.07.1-554-amd64.deb 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Reading state information... Done
This package is uninstallable
Dependency is not satisfiable: libedit2
```

I cannot seem to get the `libedit2` to install. I tried:

```
matt@matt-Rpi-2GB:~/Downloads$ sudo apt install libedit2
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
libedit2 is already the newest version (3.1-20210910-1build1).
libedit2 set to manually installed.
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  dctrl-tools dmeventd dmraid dpkg-repack efibootmgr gir1.2-timezonemap-1.0
  gir1.2-xkl-1.0 grub-common grub-efi-arm64 grub-efi-arm64-bin
  grub-efi-arm64-signed grub2-common kpartx kpartx-boot libdebian-installer4
  libdevmapper-event1.02.1 libdmraid1.0.0.rc16 libdpkg-perl
  libfile-fcntllock-perl liblvm2cmd2.03 libtimezonemap-data libtimezonemap1
  lvm2 os-prober python3-icu python3-pam rdate thin-provisioning-tools
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

How can I get the `libedit2` library to install correctly? I have had problems getting RStudio to work. I have `r-base` installed.

Data:

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy
```

Comment: The R-Studio you are trying to install is meant for PCs. It won't work in a Raspberry Pi. The Pi uses an ARM CPU similar to a smartphone. A PC uses Intel or AMD CPU.

Comment: Thanks for your response, so is it not possible to install RStudio on an Rpi?

Comment: I don't think so. Unless the company that makes RStudio decides to make a special version for Raspberry Pi. This is like trying to install a windshield made for Honda Accord on a Honda Africa! The first Honda is a car. The second one is a motorcycle.

Answer (score 1):

There is a pre-release version of arm64 RStudio Server.

RStudio Server - https://dailies.rstudio.com/rstudio/elsbeth-geranium/server/bionic-arm64/
RStudio Desktop (Electron) - https://dailies.rstudio.com/rstudio/elsbeth-geranium/electron/bionic-arm64/

Here is the GitHub Issue Link: https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/8809#issuecomment-1224856044